# last resort linux backup (rsync) will this work?

Tags: linux, centos, rsync

I have some linux servers mostly Centos Web hosting servers (Cpanel, Directadmin, kloxo).

I have some backup systems implemented, but I like to keep a local backup on my home computer. This will be used as a last resort backup.

What I do is:

1) Export mysql databases to sql files (mysqldump).
2) rsync all files exept (/) system, temporary and unessesary files to a folder in a linux system (rsync -av --delete).

I know it's not the best way to backup, but I want something fast and easy.

In case of something bad happens and for some reason my other backup solutions fail, is this enough to restore the full system ? (Reinstall the same linux system and rsync the files back).

Do you see any serious problem with that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the backup solution. One change I would make though, is to use something like etckeeper to backup the system configuration. This will give you the benefit of both backup, and change management...which also gives you the ability to step though various old configurations during the restore if you need to for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine; it's pretty much how I do my primary backups for my personal servers.

Food for thought though: You can always exclude files at restore time, you can't backup files at restore time.

IOW, backup more than you think you need. For example, I'm never confident listing specific files in `/etc` so I just backup the entire `/etc` path to make sure I have everything I need. Of course, you have to balance this with bandwidth and disk space usage on the backup target, but it might just save your day eventually.